# Hierarchy of standard-object and standard-class in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

I'm studying Common Lisp (with Lispworks) and I'm trying to get into class system right now. There is a class called **standard-object** and it is defined as

> The class **standard-object** is an instance of **standard-class** and is a superclass of every class that is an instance of **standard-class** except itself.

(taken from http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_std_ob.htm#standard-object)
so it is an instance of **standard-class**

On the other hand **standard-class** is a subclass of **standard-object**

```
>(subtypep 'standard-class 'standard-object)
=>T, T
```

How can the standard-object be a superclass for the standard-class and be its instance at the same time? If we define standard-class as a subtype, we should define it *after* defenition of its supertype (e.g. standard-object), so how can it be, that the superclass becomes the instance? Or my logic is just wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

CLOS is an object system, where CLOS concepts itself are first-class objects. Classes themselves are instances - of a meta class. There is some circularity involved.

There is an instance `standard-object`. It's an instance of `standard-class`. It is a class itself. All standard CLOS objects will have it as a superclass. There are other types of objects, for example structures. So `standard-object` is there as a superclass for all typical CLOS objects.

`standard-class` is in instance of itself. It is the class of all class objects. Since `standard-object` is also a class, the instance for the class `standard-object` is an instance of the class `standard-class`. Since all standard classes are also CLOS objects, `standard-class` inherits from `standard-object`.

```
CL-USER 22 > (class-of (find-class 'standard-object))
#<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-CLASS 40F016A063>
```

The class of the `standard-object` class object is `standard-class`.

```
CL-USER 23 > (class-of (find-class 'standard-class))
#<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-CLASS 40F016A063>
```

The class of the `standard-class` class object is `standard-class`.

```
CL-USER 24 > (find-class 'standard-object)
#<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-OBJECT 40F017732B>
```

The class `standard-object` is itself an object and a class. It is a superclass of all CLOS objects.

```
CL-USER 25 > (find-class 'standard-class)
#<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-CLASS 40F016A063>
```

The class `standard-class` is itself an object and a class. It is a superclass of all CLOS classes.

Comment: Thank you! With these examples it seems I understand now.

Comment: starting at p. 306 in Appendix D. of The Art of the Metaobject Protocol, shows code to bootstrap a CLOS-like language; includes how all of the circularity is detangled; I found it informative, although I can't yet say that I completely understand it.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this you will need to understand the concept of `meta class`. The instance of a meta class is a class and the instance of a class is an object, so basically we have 3 level hierarchy.

`standard-class` is a meta-class. `standard-object` is an instance of metaclass `standard-class` hence it is class. Every other user defined class by default inherits from `standard-object` class.

So when you are creating a class, you are basically instantiating `standard-class` metaclass and this new class is inherited by `standard-object` class.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what metaclass is, but do we define `standard-object` and `standard-class` simultaneously? In my mind everything happens like this:
0) we define class `T`;
1) we define class `standard-object`, it is a subtype of `T`; there is no `standard-class`!
2) we define `standard-class` as a subtype of `standard-object` and make it metaclass
3) `standard-object` becomes an instance of `standard-class`
Is it right? It seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: standard-class is not a subtype of standard-object. standard-object is an instance of standard-class

Comment: Then why `(subtypep 'standard-class 'standard-object)` gives answer `true`?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give an answer to only one question that seem to be confusing you:

> How can the standard-object be a superclass for the standard-class and be its
>   instance at the same time?

I hope you are familiar with the concept of relations from mathematics. Relations that are defined on a set with an operation. Examples of relation would include "is divisible by", "is a", "is equal to" etc. So, "is instance of" is a relation, "is a subclass of" is a relation too. They are by no means the same! A sub-class *must* be a class, an instance may be a class, but commonly it's something else. If you take an example from the nature: primates are a subclass of mammals - this is the "is a subclass of" relation. Lassie (a dog from a movie) is a mammal - this is an example of "is instance of" relation.

Now, what was probably confusing you is that the function of something, which is "an instance of" something else is to be that something's class. This, indeed doesn't happen much in nature, but here's something I could think of:

Language and grammar. Grammar is a set of rules, which define a language, grammar is, itself a language too (i.e. it "is a subclass of" language), while a language instantiates grammar rules, so a language "is an instance of" grammar.

Comment: That example with grammar is definitely great, thank you so much, I get everything now! I felt there is something wrong like loop in definition, but it seems alright now.